# Prolog: retract fact by it's name

Tags: prolog, fact

I want to retract fact, but I have not direct access to the name of fact.
To get anything from this fact I'd use following code:

facts.pl file:

```
:- dynamic fact/2.

fact(a, b).
fact(b, e). 
fact(a, c). 
fact(e, d). 
fact(c, d). 
fact(d, f). 
fact(d, g).
```

solution.pl file:

```
someProcedure(StructureName) :-
    call(StructureName, a, X).
```

Now how could I retract that dynamic fact from memory in solution.pl?

I've tried something like:

```
deleteProcedure(StructName, A, B) :-
    retract(call(StructName, A, B)).
```

But I get error:

```
ERROR: retract/1: No permission to modify static procedure `call/3'
ERROR: Defined at /usr/lib/swi-prolog/boot/init.pl:217
```

Comment: You've got a point. But you need to resort to pedestrian means using `(=..)/2` or `functor/3` and `arg/3` today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [univ predicate (=../2)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D..)/2) to build the term to retract.

```
retract_fact(Name, A, B) :-
  Fact =.. [Name,A,B],
  retract(Fact).
```

Note this solution accepts only atoms as the Name, so it is tailored to your example:

```
?- retract_fact(fact,a,b).
true.
```

and will not work if you pass a compound term, e.g.:

```
:- dynamic fact/3.
fact(a, b, c).

?- retract_fact(fact(a),b,c).
ERROR: Type error: `atom' expected, found `fact(a)' (a compound)
```

---

Here is a revised solution accepting compound terms:

```
retract_fact(Term, A, B) :-
  Term =.. L,
  append(L, [A,B], L1),
  Fact =.. L1,
  retract(Fact).
```

Sample run:

```
?- retract_fact(fact(a),b,c).
true.

?- retract_fact(fact,b,e).
true.
```

Comment: Which is not **exactly** the same as `call/3` since the 1st argument there is not limited to an atom.

Comment: You are right. This answer is tailored to OP example. I will mention it

Comment: What about a more generic mechanism?

Comment: A list could be used to add any amount of parameters instead of the fixed 2 that OP had in his question. Is that what you imply with a "more generic mechanism" ?

Comment: But then, we have `call/N` and no longer `apply/2` which uses such a list....